# Yii 2 framework on mac

Tags: yii

I do not know why it has to be so hard installing Yii 2 framework on a mac. I have been reading on this page:

[Yii 2 installation](http://www.yiiframework.com/download/)

What is all this composer, and how and where should I install that composer? I have now tried to download the "install from archive file, and put the folder in my htdocs folder"

[image: Archive file]

But where do I go from here? I cannot figure out?

Best Regards

**Update**

[image]

Comment: Have you seen the Guide? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I just tried with your link, and made an update on my question, because I get an error, when I run the second line. The terminal says that I do not have access?

Comment: Looks like you need `sudo` for this.

Comment: I am gonna give up and choose another one. I never understood why there cannot be an eaiser way for people who are not so good yet. 10.000 steps before a framework is installed.

Comment: Don't give up, just follow instructions step by step. By the way - using composer is the proper way of dealing with PHP in 2016, sooner or later you will have to get to know it.

Comment: I got it installed :) Thank you a lot for the chearing up.